# How can post the message on Facebook wall using accesstoken in android?

Tags: android

I used the following code to post a image with text. It working fine.

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token="
                        + accessToken);
        URL url = new URL("Some Image URL");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bi.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
        entity.addPart("source", new ByteArrayBody(data, "sample.png"));
        entity.addPart("message", new StringBody("Text need to be posted"));
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                localContext);
        Log.v("response ", response + "");
```

In my another activity i need to post message only (text) so i commented this line `entity.addPart("source", new ByteArrayBody(data, "sample.png"));`, the text won't post on my wall. How can i modify this code to post only the text